# Cumulocity single sign-on - authenticating with a microservice in the context of a SSO user

Tags: cumulocity

Our c8y tenant has single sign-on configured with an external openid connect provider. Users can login via the SSO and access c8y UI apps - cockpit, etc.

However, when a user tries to access an endpoint of a microservice(e.g. the /health endpoint of a custom microservice), a pop-up appears asking for credentials.

My question is regarding this scenario - a user signs in via SSO and loads a custom c8y web app, where JavaScript code calls an endpoint on a back-end microservice. What needs to be done so that the microservice authenticates the user correctly, and is able to extract data about the user - username, roles, tenant(in the case of a multi-tenant MS).

If the user is logged in as a regular c8y user, the Java microservice SDK handles this - how does it work with SSO?

Answer (score 2):

Mihail please take a look at the documentation part [here](https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/concept#security). Microservice SDK will take care of it automatically since 9.20. Thus please make sure your microservices implement the right version.